# .NET - Messages broker sharing data model

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue

I have a question regarding sending messages through a message broker. I'm working on a .NET application using clean architecture and I have a SharedContracts project where I have message wrappers that are shared across other services. I'm sending a message through the message broker indicating that there is a file in the blob storage that can be worked with. The data is in JSON format. Is it appropriate to create a model of this JSON in the SharedContracts project and distribute it to other projects? Typically, this model is inside the message and I can work with it. Thank you.

Comment: Sure how else would you make sure that all ends of the queue know how to interpret the message? If its shared knowledge it can also be a shared class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I appreciated it. I wasn't sure because the message itself doesn't actually contain information about what data model will actually be used there, as the data itself is stored on disk. Or should I, for example, create a null model in the message? That would actually solve it. And just one more thing, can I add a reference to the domain model in the shared contracts? So that I don't duplicate code?

Comment: JSON data does not need a model.  It is a dictionary with keys and values.  You can parse it without a model, although is many cases it is easy to work with the data as classes (model).  What transmitting JSON intermediate points can just pass the JSON as text.  Only the final endpoints in most cases need to be able to be able to parse the data.